# Kafka MirrorMaker's consumer not fetching all messages from topics

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I am trying to setup a Kafka Mirror mechanism, but it seems the Kafka MirrorMaker's consumer from the source Kafka cluster only reads from new incoming data to the topics as soon as the mirror maker process is started, i.e. it does not read historically saved data in the topics previously.

I am using Kafka MirrorMaker class for that as:

`/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --consumer.config consumer.config --num.streams 2 --producer.config producer.config --whitelist=".*"`

`consumer.config` to read from Kafka source cluster, as:

`zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181`

`zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000`

`group.id=kafka-mirror`

and `producer.config` settings to produce to the new Kafka mirrored cluster:

`metadata.broker.list=localhost:9093`

`producer.type=sync`

`compression.codec=none`

`serializer.class=kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder`

Is there a way to define the consumer of Kafka MirrorMaker to read from the beginning of the topics of my source Kafka cluster? A bit strange, because I have defined in the `consumer.config` settings a new consumer group (`kafka-mirror`), so the consumer should just read from `offset 0`, i.e. from beginning of topics.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

In consumer properties, add

`auto.offset.reset=earliest`

This should work

Answer (score 6):

Look at the `auto.offset.reset` parameter from Kafka consumer configuration.

From Kafka documentation:

> auto.offset.reset     largest
>
> What to do when there is no initial offset in Zookeeper or if an
>   offset is out of range:
>   * smallest : automatically reset the offset to the smallest offset
>   * largest : automatically reset the offset to the largest offset
>   * anything else: throw exception to the consumer. If this is set to largest, the consumer may lose some messages when the number of
>   partitions, for the topics it subscribes to, changes on the broker. To
>   prevent data loss during partition addition, set auto.offset.reset to
>   smallest

So, using `smallest` for `auto.offset.reset` should fix your problem.

Comment: Ran into the same issue, tried this same solution. No dice. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer but this might be helpful to some one who is still looking for.

As of now kafka mirror doesn't support this. There is an open defect .[KafkaMirror](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4668)